# Get 1 query value to a variable

Tags: php, mysqli

I am running a query and i need to get only 1 value. i currently have,

```
$sql = "SELECT userId FROM UserAccountInfo WHERE loginName = '$userName'";
$result = $con->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);
$userId = $row[0];
```

i need a shorter way to get userId to a variable. there a way i don't have to use the fetch_array thing. i know there is only one thing in the query so why use an array.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @p he wants a shorter way!

Comment: This question is off-topic until you can explain *why* you *need* to do this

Comment: i would like to know if there is a way to get 1 value from a query without having to put it in an array first to shorten my code. what is there that you don't understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint about the length of the code but instead of interpolating query strings and leaving your code wide open to sql injection attacks you should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

That being said this part of code might look like

```php
$sql = "SELECT userId FROM UserAccountInfo WHERE loginName = ?";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $userName);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($userId);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Now if you do it a lot (getting scalar values from your DB) and don't want repetitive code all over then write a wrapper function or opt out to one of the ORM frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

add LIMIT clause at the end of query.

```
WHERE loginName = '$userName' LIMIT 0,1"
                -------------^^^^^^^^^^-
```

Comment: i was having problems with the site accepting my questing so i edited the post to add what else i needed please help again.

Answer (score -1):

Use the LIMIT in the SQL and use this PHP

```
$result = $con->query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$userId = $row['userId'];
```